# Add column values to eachother in PHP and MYSQLI

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've been trying to figure out how to count all column values and add them to each other.

[image]

What i want to achieve is that my code will calculate all the price values, where check = 1 and add them to eachother as $total.

My goal : So i can divide the total result where check = 1, and check is 0, and subtract them from eachother.

*I apologize for my paint skills.*

Comment: So have you tried anything for yourself yet? Or were you expecting us to do it for you?

Comment: I have, but i have no idea how i could get this to work. I can get all the results, but i don't know how to get them to seperate, and add to eachother..

Comment: @Akintunde I don't, but i could use a guide in the right direction on how to tackle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT sum(price) as Total from YOUR_TABLE where `check` = 1;
```

Comment: Note: `check` is a reserved word and therefore would require wrapping in backticks for this to compile

Comment: Noted, thanks for the help. I've tried similar things, but i could not get it to work. Glad you could help me out.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following:

```
Step 1: Query all results from the table.
Step 2: Loop through the result.
Step 3: Create two array array1 and array2
Step 4: Inside the loop check condition if (check == 1) stored price value in array1 else if (check == 0) store in array2
Step 5: sum values of array1 and array2 in different variables and finally subtract from each other.
```

or try the following query:

```
 SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN check='0' THEN price END) as zerossum,
        SUM(CASE WHEN check='1' THEN price END) as onessum
  FROM tablename
```

Comment: Note: `check` is a reserved word and therefore would require wrapping in backticks for this to compile

Answer (score 1):

You can get the complete answer using just SQL if you want

```
SELECT ones - zeros as theTotal
FROM
(
    SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN `check`=0 THEN price END) as zeros,
           SUM(CASE WHEN `check`=1 THEN price END) as ones
    FROM test
) test1;
```